# Symfony 3.4 routing seems does not work

Tags: routes, symfony-3.4

I created a new project with `symfony new myproject 3.4` and in the fresh project, I simple copy-paste the indexAction in the default controller, rename the action and the route, and voila, the server returned a 404 not found error.  I did nothing more.

Of course I also have the `type: annotation` in my routing.yml file.

What could be the problem? Any idea? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a caching issue, you can clear the cache by issuing the command `bin/console cache:clear` from your command prompt.

Comment: I thought that symfony caches only the views not the controllers. I have cleared the cache from command line, but it didnt help. After that I hardly remove all the contents from the cache folder, and the page going to work.
So, thank you for your suggestion! :)

Comment: Symfony not only caches views, but also all the data which is in the annotations, therefor whenever you modify annotations you'll need to refresh the cache.